# React - Component rendering weather data

Tags: javascript, html, hash-map, react.js, jsx

Background:

Hello, I'm a student (since 2 months) and I've created a small MVP of a weather application. So now I'm refactoring my code because it looks hideous and it is hard to work with.

The problem:

In the snippet I will provide you will see that I repeat code for a .map(), which I know is not the best practice. But I need help to know in which way I could combine the two loops to one, and still render the same result from my component.

This is probably a simple problem, but I struggle right now with the nesting. I think it's actually more about the html table rather than the .js itself. But I just keep bashing my head here.

What my code does:

This is a html Table from a component that formats and renders weather data fetched from a public API, in 3 columns per row, date, time of day and weather data values.

The loops themselves maps through a weather json object so I can render the timestamps and the weather data I want to show to the user.

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th className="date">Date</th>
            <th className="time">Time</th>
            <th className="values">Value/Unit</th>
          </tr>
          {dates.map((weatherDate, index) => {
            if (
              index === 0 ||
              weather[weatherDate].length < 4
            ) {
              return null;
            }
            return weather[weatherDate] && weather[weatherDate].length !== 0 ? (
              <React.Fragment key={"thisWeek-" + index}>
                <tr className="tr-content">
                  <td className="date">{weatherDate}</td>
                  <td className="time">
                    {weather[weatherDate].map((weatherData, _index) => {
                      const time = weatherData.validTime.slice(
                        weatherData.validTime.indexOf("T") + 1,
                        weatherData.validTime.length - 4
                      );
                      if (TIMES_TO_SHOW.indexOf(time) === -1) return null;
                      return (
                        <p key={"weather-data-" + _index}>
                          {time}
                        </p>
                      );
                    })}
                  </td>
                  <td className="values">
                    {weather[weatherDate].map((weatherTime, index_) => {
                      const time = weatherTime.validTime.slice(
                        weatherTime.validTime.indexOf("T") + 1,
                        weatherTime.validTime.length - 4
                      );
                      if (TIMES_TO_SHOW.indexOf(time) === -1) return null;
                      return (
                        <React.Fragment key={index_}>
                          Temperature: {weatherTime.parameters.t.values}°
                          Windspeed: {weatherTime.parameters.ws.values} m/s
                          Gusts: {weatherTime.parameters.gust.values} m/s
                          Vind direction: {weatherTime.parameters.wd.values}°
                        </React.Fragment>
                      );
                    })}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : null;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I am aware of other problems in my code, feel free to adress them as well, but I'm mainly here for help with combining my loops :)

Comment: Welcome to code review. Please check the [ask] page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hey Jonathan, welcome to Code Review!

There's an easy way to turn those two `map`s into one. I'm going to tell you how, and give you some general tips as a bonus. Buckle up!

---

## ➰ [Looping right round (like a record baby)](https://youtu.be/PGNiXGX2nLU?t=61)

You asked how to prevent yourself from repeating your loops, which is [a perfect use case for a `Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)!

Consider the following:

```
<row>
    <column>
      {data.map(item => /*...*/)}
    </column>
    <column>
      {data.map(item => /*...*/)}
    </column>
</row>
```

Assuming those two maps are over the same data, and use the same parameters, we can just wrap the `column`s in a fragment in a single loop:

```
<row>
    {data.map(item => (
        <React.fragment>
            <column>
                {item}
            </column>
            <column>
                {item}
            </column>
        </React.fragment>
    ))}
</row>
```

So to answer your question:

```
{weather[weatherDate].map((weatherData, index) => {
    const time = weatherData.validTime.slice(
        weatherData.validTime.indexOf("T") + 1,
        weatherData.validTime.length - 4
    );
    if (TIMES_TO_SHOW.indexOf(time) === -1) return null;
    return (
        <React.Fragment key={"thisWeek-" + index}>
            <td className="time">
                <p key={"weather-data-" + index}>
                    {time}
                </p>
            </td>
            <td className="values">
                <React.Fragment key={index_}>
                    Temperature: {weatherData.parameters.t.values}°
                    Windspeed: {weatherData.parameters.ws.values} m/s
                    Gusts: {weatherData.parameters.gust.values} m/s
                    Vind direction: {weatherData.parameters.wd.values}°
                </React.Fragment>
            </td>
        </React.fragment>
    );
})}
```

Okay, bye!

...

Kidding! There's more where that came from.

---

## ❓ To render or not to render

### ️ Skipping unwanted values

When mapping over an array of values, you might run into values that you don't want to map. When something like that happens, you might want to return `null` instead of that value -- which is what you've done here.

```js
dates.map((weatherDate, index) => {
    if (
        weather[weatherDate].length < 4
    ) {
        return null;
    }
    /* ... */
);
```

Looking at the code and stepping back a bit, you're putting business logic into your view logic. This makes code more cryptic and thus more difficult to understand. We need to separate "should we render this data?" from "how to render this data?".

Instead of returning `null` which tells React not to render this data, surely one could just just... *not render those values in the array in the first place?* This is where [our great friend `Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) comes in. It takes a function that returns a boolean for each element in an array, called a *predicate*. If that predicate returns `true`, the element in question is "kept" -- else the element is "discarded":

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const isEven = number => number % 2 === 0;
const evenNumbers = numbers.filter(number => isEven(number));
// > [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Side-note: `x => y(x)` is the same as just `y`, so the last line could be refactored:

```
const evenNumbers = numbers.filter(isEven);
```

How clean is that?!

Applying this newfound knowledge, your code could look like this:

```
const isValidDate = date => weather[date].length >= 4;
// ...
return dates
    .filter(isValidDate)
    .map(/*...*/);
```

In a later mapping, you check if some date is a member of the set `DATES_TO_SHOW`, and return `null` if it isn't:

```
weather[weatherDate].map((weatherTime, _index) => {
    const time = weatherTime.validTime.slice(
        weatherTime.validTime.indexOf("T") + 1,
        weatherTime.validTime.length - 4
    );
    if (TIMES_TO_SHOW.indexOf(time) === -1) return null;
    return (
        <p key={"weather-data-" + _index}>
            {time}
        </p>
    );
}
```

We just learned that we should filter out unwanted items before we render, so let's take a look at how we could solve this:

```
const weatherToTime = weatherTime => weatherTime.validTime.slice(
    weatherTime.validTime.indexOf("T") + 1,
    weatherTime.validTime.length - 4
);
const shouldShowTime = time => TIMES_TO_SHOW.includes(time);
// Notice how I used Array.includes instead of .indexOf(x) === -1
// as .includes is much more autological

weather[weatherDate]
    .map(weatherToTime)
    .filter(shouldShowTime)
    .map((time, _index) => (
        <p key={"weather-data-" + _index}>
            {time}
        </p>
    );
```

### Slice it up

Sometimes you just don't care about the first `n` elements of an array.

```js
dates.map((weatherDate, index) => {
    if (
        index === 0
    ) {
        return null;
    }
    /* ... */
);
```

You could check the index in every iteration and return `null` in iteration zero, but, again, *what if we could skip rendering that item completely?*

In some languages there's a function called `skip` or `drop`, and [in javascript we have `Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Since you used slice in your code, you might already know how it works so you might want to *skip* over the next codeblock.

With `slice` you can skip some elements from the start of an array, and optionally drop some from its end:

```js
const digitsAndLetters = [0, 1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c", "d"];
const letters = digitsAndLetters.slice(4);
// > ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const digits = digitsAndLetters.slice(0, 4);
// > [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So in your case, to skip the first element of `dates`, we slice 1 item off the start:

```js
dates
    .slice(1)
    .filter(isValidDate)
    .map(/* ... */);
```

*Ooh baby, look at that!*  Not only does this just look nicer, it also reduces cognitive load when trying to understand what your code does. Again: separate "*what* do we render?" and "*how* do we render?" Separating *what* and *how* is actually a great refactoring for all code.

---

## ️ Meaningful keys

[You really shouldn't be using the map index as a key.](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) Why? In short: React uses keys to identify elements between renders. This means that react assumes keys are *stable*, meaning the key to some data must always be the same. When using `index` as a key, you're coupling data to something *unrelated* (i.e. the iteration count) and thus unstable (sorting your list would change the order of data but not the order of `index` which might result in render bugs).

In your case it's  not directly a concern, but anything that *can* go wrong, *will* go wrong.

A simple solution is to use some identifying property of your data. Maybe some property `id` exists? Or another property that differs from item to item? If you have a date, you could for example `.toString()` it. If it's a complex object [you could hash its contents to get a unique identifying value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Depending on your data, you should be using one of these approaches (or something similar).

```
data.map(item => (
  <div key={item.id}/>
  <div key={item.toString()}/>
  <div key={hash(item)}/>
))
```

---

## Embrace expressions

You write a lot of arrow functions with blocks, which kind of defeat their purpose. In most languages an arrow function (often called a lambda) is a syntactical construct to take one argument and transform it, returning the result of that transformation. In other words, there is an implicit `return` when you don't use blocks:

```js
const double = (number) => {
  return number * 2;
};
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const doubledNumbers = numbers.map(double);
//> [2, 4, 6];
```

can also be expressed as

```js
const double = number => number * 2;
// Note that parentheses are optional when working
// with a single parameter
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const doubledNumbers = numbers.map(double);
//> [2, 4, 6];
```

The following is a little rant so feel free to skip to the recap.

I don't know why the people in the ECMAScript committee decided blocks should be allowed in arrow functions. We already had `function () {}`. Because blocks and object literals use the same characters in the grammar, we need to put parentheses around an object in an arrow function:

```js
// You could be fooled into thinking this would return an object
const Person = name => {
  name: name,
  age: Math.random()
};
// But no, that's a syntax error -- javascript is trying to parse it
// as a block. We need to put parentheses around it to tell javascript
// we're definitely giving it an expression here.
const Person = name => ({
  name: name,
  age: Math.random()
});
```

Arrgh!!

---

## Recap

All right, we've done it! Hopefully you learned a thing or two. The main takeaways are:

- Use `Fragment`s to group data.
- Separate ***what*** from ***how***.
- Use meaningful keys for jsx elements in React.
- [Don't get RSI](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/repetitive-strain-injury-rsi/): (x) => { return y; } is the same as x => y.
- [To use a beautifully apt quote from Dieter Rams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieter_Rams#%22Good_design%22_principles): Less is more ([unless you're Yngwie Malmsteen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHZ48AE3TOI)).